# Dynamic DataGrid in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid, callback, resultset

I am trying to construct a DataGrid in GWT that will show an arbitrary dataset taken from an rpc method.

I have done some progress as I get the fields from a method and the data from another.
I have managed to construct the Datagrid and add the columns from the rpc.getFields() method and fill the table using an AsyncDataProvider.
The problem is that when I refresh the browser, it duplicates all the columns at the Datagrid. I cannot figure out what to do. I tried to remove first all the columns but no luck.

I attach the code if anyone have an idea.

```
public class MyCallBack implements AsyncCallback<List<Field>> {

DataGrid<Record> dg;



public MyCallBack(DataGrid<Record> dgrid) { 
    this.dg=dgrid;

}

public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
    Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
}

public void onSuccess(List<Field> result) { 
    for (int i=0;i<=result.size();i++) {            
        IndexedColumn ic = new IndexedColumn(i);
        dg.addColumn(ic, result.get(i).getLabel());         
    }           
}

public AsyncCallback<List<Field>> getCb() {
    return this;
}
```

---

```
public void onModuleLoad() {

    final DataGrid<Record> dg = new DataGrid<Record>();     

    MyCallBack mcb = new MyCallBack(dg);
    DataProvider dp = new DataProvider();

    DBConnectionAsync rpcService = (DBConnectionAsync) GWT.create(DBConnection.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) rpcService;
    String moduleRelativeURL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "MySQLConnection";
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(moduleRelativeURL);

    rpcService.getFields(mcb.getCb()); 

    dp.addDataDisplay(dg);      
    dg.setVisibleRange(0, 200);
    SplitLayoutPanel slp = new SplitLayoutPanel();
    slp.setHeight("700px");
    slp.setWidth("1500px");
    slp.addWest(dg, 770);

    RootPanel.get().add(slp);         
  }
```

Comment: How did you try to remove all the columns first?

Comment: Aftes onSuccess, I used: "dg.removeColumn(0);"

Comment: You put it in a loop to remove all columns right?

Comment: Yes,: for (int i=0;i<=dg.getColumnCount();i++) {
   dg.removeColumn(i);
  }.  And I get ena empty panel.

Comment: try using the clearing method I wrote in my answer because your method might not work if the data grid changes the index of all columns once you delete one of them. I'm not sure about it though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh a browser, all UI is lost. There is no difference between (a) show the UI for the first time or (b) show the UI after browser refresh.

Your comment "Only if I restart tomcat it works" suggests that the problem is on the server side. Most likely, you return twice the number of data points on a second call.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I found the problem.
My List<Field> on the server-side was out of the getFields() method...

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the table before filling it like this:

```
public void onSuccess(List<Field> result) { 
    clearTable();

    for (int i=0;i<=result.size();i++) {            
        IndexedColumn ic = new IndexedColumn(i);
        dg.addColumn(ic, result.get(i).getLabel());         
    }           
}

private void clearTable(){
    while (dg.getColumnCount() > 0) {
        db.removeColumn(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now the app loads for the first time but on refresh It doubles the columns.
Only if I restart tomcat it works.